# Create a Variable with value one after "treatment" in year X, and 0 otherwise

Tags: r, dummy-variable, panel-data

I have a panel data of Brazilian municipalities comprising the years 1995-2013. Code is the municipality ID. Nome is the municipality name, and ano is the year of the adoption of a public policy (zero means that they never implemented the policy.)

```
     code                 Nome  ano
1 1100015 ALTA FLORESTA DOESTE 2010
2 1100023            ARIQUEMES 2006
3 1100031               CABIXI    0
4 1100049               CACOAL 2006
5 1100056           CEREJEIRAS 2014
6 1100064    COLORADO DO OESTE 2006
```

I have the following question:

How do I generate a dummy variable in R with value 1 after the adoption of a public policy by municipality X in year Z, and 0 otherwise?

Below you can see the expected output in a wide format, which is easier to visualize. (However, I will transform the data into a long format to merge with other data. As you can see, ones in this example only start after 2006, or never.)

```
      code                      Nome 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
1  1100015      ALTA FLORESTA DOESTE    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
2  1100023                 ARIQUEMES    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
3  1100031                    CABIXI    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4  1100049                    CACOAL    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
5  1100056                CEREJEIRAS    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6  1100064         COLORADO DO OESTE    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I have found similar questions in this forum, but not the one I'm asking.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`.  Create a `list` column with sequence from each value of 'ano' to 2013, `unnest` the `list` column, create a column of 1s ('val'), grouped by 'code', 'Nome', expand the dataset with `complete` for sequence from 1995 to 2013, while `fill`ing the 'val' with 0 where the combination is not present, `ungroup` and reshape it to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #1.0.0
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(ano = case_when(between(ano, 1995, 2013) ~ 
        map(ano, ~ .x:2013), TRUE ~ list(NA_integer_))) %>% 
   unnest(ano) %>% 
   mutate(val = 1) %>%
   group_by(code, Nome) %>% 
   complete(ano = 1995:2013, fill = list(val = 0)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   filter(!is.na(ano)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = ano, values_from = val)
# A tibble: 6 x 21
#     code Nome                 `1995` `1996` `1997` `1998` `1999` `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010` `2011` `2012` `2013`
#    <int> <chr>                 <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 1100015 ALTA FLORESTA DOESTE      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1
#2 1100023 ARIQUEMES                 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
#3 1100031 CABIXI                    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
#4 1100049 CACOAL                    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
#5 1100056 CEREJEIRAS                0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
#6 1100064 COLORADO DO OESTE         0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(code = c(1100015L, 1100023L, 1100031L, 1100049L, 
1100056L, 1100064L), Nome = c("ALTA FLORESTA DOESTE", "ARIQUEMES", 
"CABIXI", "CACOAL", "CEREJEIRAS", "COLORADO DO OESTE"), ano = c(2010L, 
2006L, 0L, 2006L, 2014L, 2006L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. When I use real data, I get the following message: "Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double]." Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @user1290547  Can you check the `str(yourdata)` with that of `str(df1)`  it could be that the 'ano' in your original dataset is not numeric.

Comment: Thank you again! You have been very helpful! I checked the str(mydata), and you were right - ano was a character. Then, I changed the way I encode my data, and the code worked. I'm still getting the following msg: "Warning message:
between() called on numeric vector with S3 class." I don't know if this is important. Sorry, I'm relatively new to R.

Comment: @user1290547 If it is a warning and still works, it is not that problematic as it could be a friendly warning